# php convert date to MySQL date

Tags: php, date

I need to convert a date in this format:

> November 28, 2009

to a MySQL date format:

> 2009-28-11

What's the best method to convert the date using PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Improvised from: http://www.bigroom.co.uk/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $phpdate ) );

// Example:
$phpdate = 'November 20, 2009';
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $phpdate ) );

echo $mysqldate;
// output: 2009-11-20
```

Comment: Darn - beat me by just a few seconds.  Good answer.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a "date" to be converted to "DateTime" this is the best way =

```
// for example: you have a string with the following
$dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
$dateString = '02/12/2019';

// you can easily create DateTime using
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $dateString);
```

As described in the [php documentation for createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

And to answer completely on your question:

```
echo $dateTime->format('y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function as follows:

`$mysql_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($source_date));`

Answer (score 1):

There are two options you can use which are `strtotime` or `preg_split` and `sprintf`. I recommend you use `strtotime`. The structure goes like this:

```
$date = 'November 28 2009';
$sqldate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Make sure the Y is capital so it reads as 0000 otherwise it will read 00.

Comment: What do you mean with preg_split  and sprintf? Can you give an example?